# Angular2 with Spring Boot script not executed

Tags: spring, angular, spring-boot

I was following this tutorial here: https://blog.jdriven.com/2016/12/angular2-spring-boot-getting-started/ to create an Angular 2 application working with Spring Boot. Unfortunately, at the step where you fire up the application it shows me only the static "Loading..." from the main app-module tag in the body which is NOT replaced by a Compenent content (App works!). So why is the code from my components not being executed?

I do have output in the target-folder and the only things I changed while following the tutorial was changing project name and versions of node and npm.

EDIT: when I try to start a server with "ng serve --open" without an IDE, from the frontend directory, I get the same problem.

In the browser you can see the Error "Uncaught reflect-metadata shim is required when using class decorators"

EDIT2: previously I ran the original source code from the tutorial and it worked. now I have the same error with it! I assume the problem is somewhere with the global installation of node/npm?

Comment: Is there any error shown in the JavaScript console of your browser?

Comment: @Henry Yes: Uncaught reflect-metadata shim is required when using class decorators